High latency in SipSorcery call between softphone and physical handset, but only in one direction
We're having quite a specific issue, and I'd appreciate some advice on how to resolve it if possible.
We have a phone system running on Asterisk, and I'm implementing a softphone component in one of our applications using SipSorcery on C#.
In this particular use case, both a physical Cisco handset and the softphone connect to a conference on the Asterisk server.
Audio from the softphone to the handset is sent with a minimal latency, and is working perfectly fine.
Audio from the Cisco handset back to the softphone however initially had a delay of around 4 seconds between speaking and the sound being played back on the softphone.
I have added a buffer with a packet timeout of 40ms, and this appears to have improved the issue, however we still have a delay of around 1 second.
When connecting 2 Cisco phones into the same conference, there is no significant latency, and as this issue only happens from the physical phone to the softphone, I believe that this is in some way related to the decoding of the packets.
The implementation is using NAudio (via SipSorceryMedia.Windows), and I'm using a VoipMediaSession to handle the RTP.
I'd be grateful for any help in resolving this. I've spent the past 3 days experimenting and trawling the github posts, but so far have not been able to make much headway.
audioEndpoint = new WindowsAudioEndPoint(encoder, outputDeviceIndex, inputDeviceIndex);

List<AudioFormat> sinkFormats = audioEndpoint.GetAudioSinkFormats();
List<AudioFormat> sourceFormats = audioEndpoint.GetAudioSourceFormats();


AudioFormat sourceAudioFormat = sourceFormats.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FormatName == "PCMA");
audioEndpoint.SetAudioSourceFormat(sourceAudioFormat);


AudioFormat sinkAudioFormat = sinkFormats.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FormatName == "PCMA");      
audioEndpoint.SetAudioSinkFormat(sinkAudioFormat);

MediaEndPoints endpoints = audioEndpoint.ToMediaEndPoints();
            
voipMediaSession = new VoIPMediaSession(audioEndpoint.ToMediaEndPoints());
voipMediaSession.AcceptRtpFromAny = true;
voipMediaSession.AudioExtrasSource.AudioSamplePeriodMilliseconds = 500;

TimeSpan packetTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 40);
voipMediaSession.AudioStream.AddBuffer(packetTimeout);

